# jQuery val() returns an array with IE8 on select/option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The following alert returns "string" in the majors browsers. Returns "object" (an array of one element) on <=IE8.

HTML:

```
<SELECT id="adults_1" type="select">
    <OPTION value="1">1 persona</OPTION>
</SELECT>​
```

JS:

```
 alert(typeof $("#adults_1").val());
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JM9AY/2/

Is it a bug or it is the expected value? If it's a bug, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing `type="select"` corrects this unexpected behavior. What is the meaning of the `type` attribute here in any case? There is no such attribute in HTML5.

Comment: The question is, why this attribute is making IE8 to have this behaviour ?

Comment: @JordiPlanadecursach: No idea :) Would have to start from reading the jQuery sources in order to investigate.

Comment: Also occurs with type='text' (not sure why that one was there...). Probably any type attribute.